# Trouble passing in additional parameters in function

Tags: javascript, json, function, d3.js

I'm trying to write a function in d3 that will check the "time" of my data and see whether it is between two other times, and filter accordingly.

```
//start with a function to check if time for each data point is in between two other times
function timeInterval(data, start, end) {
    var time = data.Time

    if (start <= time <= end) {           
        return "inline";
    } else {
        return "none";
    };   
 }

//set the display of points to either inline or none
function updateTime(value) {
d3.selectAll(".events")
    .style("display", timeInterval("20:00", "24:00"));    
}


//When radio button on, call updateTime function
d3.selectAll("#timeFilterRadioButton").on("change", function() {
updateTime()
});
```

My issue is that I'm unable to call `timeInterval` with the start and end parameters.  Calling `timeInterval("20:00", "24:00")` results in time being undefined.  The only way I can successfully pass in the data is if I call the function without any parameters:

```
 function updateTime(value) {
     d3.selectAll(".events")
        .style("display", timeInterval); //calling timeInterval in this manner, I'm able to console.log the time property of the data   
 }
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use an anonymous function to get the data and wrap your `timeInterval` function in it:

```
function updateTime(value) {
    d3.selectAll(".events")
        .style("display", function(d) {
            //your datum is here---^
            return timeInterval(d, "20:00", "24:00")
            //use it here-------^
        });
};
```

Not related, but this:

```
if (start <= time <= end)
```

Will return `true` for all `start <= time`, regardless `end`.

Comment: I was about to write that your last sentence was ambiguous when I noticed there is more to it! `("22:00" <= "23:00" <= "21:00") === false` for all possible strings. The first comparison will work as expected resulting in a boolean value which, evaluating further ltr, will be compared to a non-empty string. For that comparison the last string will be coerced to a number yielding `NaN` because of the colon evaluating internally to undefined which (https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-relational-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) returns `false` for the entire expression.

Comment: Note, how this differs when comparing numerical values: `(1 <= 2 <= 3) === true` vs. `(1 <= 2 <= 0) === false` vs. `(2 <= 1 <= 3) === true` vs. `(2 <= 1 <= -3) === false`. Just when it starts getting boring you throw in some funky type coercion!

Comment: @altocumulus But there are some problems regarding numbers as well. Try `(1 < 3 < 2)`, it results `true`: `1 < 3 < 2` --> `true < 2` --> `1 < 2` --> `true`. My goal here was showing OP that they should do **two** comparisons: `if(foo < bar && bar < baz)`.

Comment: Sure. I didn't mean to say that numerical comparision worked better than string comparison, though. The third expression in my second comment is also not correct, at least not mathematically correct. I just wanted to point out the peculiarities and subtleties of type coercion in JS. Although the expression is syntactically valid I am sure we can agree on `(start <= time && time <= end)` being the right statement for OP's needs.